# How should I read the Star Wars books?

Tags: star-wars, books, suggested-order

I've been a fan of the Star Wars movies since I was a kid, but I've never read any of the books. Every time I've thought about reading them, I change my mind because there is so many books, I don't know where to start.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_books

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_books

I don't live anywhere near a public library, and I don't have a lot of money to spend on 200+ books. I'm going to be buying the books for my e-reader with Christmas gift cards.

I've heard about The Thrawn Trilogy by Timothy Zahn, and The Darth Bane Trilogy by Drew Karpyshyn. The Thrawn Trilogy sounds really good, but since Bane isn't in the movies, is it worth it reading about characters I don't know? Is that one of those books I would have to read more in the universe before reading? Is it any good?

I'm interested in learning more about the characters in the original trilogy and the prequels. So, my question is, how do I read them? Do I read them in chronological order? Will I be completely lost if I read them out of order?

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order+star-wars

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Since book recommendations are off-topic here, I've removed that part of your question to avoid it being closed. I've read some of the Thrawn books and quite liked them; I'm looking forward to seeing the answers.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach I would recommend is using Star Wars Wikia as your guide.

Read:

- By character. Find all books mentioning a character on the Wikia page for it.
- By timeline. There's "New Republic" books (Luke/Han/Leia stuff in 10 or so years past Yavin, chronologically starting with Truce at Bakura and ending with Vision of the Future). You can read specific arcs within that (Han+Leia arc; Mara Jade arc; Thrawn arc). Then there are other timelines (New Jedi Order covering Vong war, Legacy stuff even later on, Clone Wars books, and Old Republic coverng events long before the movies).
- By events/topics. Again, go into Wikia, pick a set of topics to read about (superweapons) and read the books references on those pages.
- Chronologically in-universe. SFF.SE has questions covering that.

The important part is that Wikia can help you both guide/focus your interest; AND allow you to fill in holes for things that matter but happened in the books you didn't read; AND allow you to preview what the book covers before buying it.

But do NOT NOT NOT skip Zahn. His books are nearly unanimously among the best in 100s of works of EU material.

---

P.S. Just to get you even more depressed - you can also <strike>waste</strike> spend money on comic books and games that contain EU material, some that is interesting/important. Or simply read plot summaries on Wikia :)

Comment: Definitely agree on Zahn. His books are easily the best of them all, and his Thrawn trilogy is probably the best arc ever written about Star Wars

Answer (score 3):

There's an extensive discussion of the most popular Star Wars books [here](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2013/01/where-to-begin-with-star-wars-books).

Those written by Timothy Zahn and Kathy Tyers seem to have the most support from fans but with over 200+ published non-canon books, an equal number of ebooks and over 31,000 [fanfics](https://www.fanfiction.net/movie/Star-Wars/) (most of which are written as stand-alone stories) you can pretty much dive in wherever you like.

My advice would be to try to work out what you actually want to see more of. If you're into [romance](http://roqoodepot.com/2012/02/14/valentines-day-star-wars-romance-novels/) then these will probably be your choice, if you're after [grittier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345461150) then these would probably suit you, if you're into Star Wars erotica then [fanfiction](http://movies.adult-fanfiction.org/main.php?cat=8) is definitely going to be your main option.

[image: bookcase filled with dozens of Star Wars novels]

Comment: -1 for "Shadow Moon" in the corner <g>