# Star Wars Expanded Universe

Tags: star-wars

I am interested in getting into the Star Wars Expanded Universe, and was wondering what would be the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Per my [earlier answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/how-should-i-read-the-star-wars-books/47504#47504);

There's an extensive discussion of the most popular Star Wars books [here](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2013/01/where-to-begin-with-star-wars-books).

Those written by Timothy Zahn and Kathy Tyers seem to have the most support from fans but with over 200+ published non-canon books, an equal number of ebooks and over 31,000 [fanfics](https://www.fanfiction.net/movie/Star-Wars/) (most of which are written as stand-alone stories) you can pretty much dive in wherever you like.

My advice would be to try to work out what you actually want to see more of. If you're into romance then [these](http://roqoodepot.com/2012/02/14/valentines-day-star-wars-romance-novels/) will probably be your choice, if you're after something grittier then [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345461150) would probably suit you, if you're into Star Wars erotica then [fanfiction](http://movies.adult-fanfiction.org/main.php?cat=8) is definitely going to be your main option.

[image: Star Wars Books]